# Sistema de login (erro quando tiver banido)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema de login e queria que aparecesse **ERRO** se o usuário estiver banido.
O nome da SQL na tabela é "ban", se "ban" for igual a "0" o usuário não estará banido, e se "ban" for igual a "1" o usuário vai estar banido e não poderá logar.

Código:

```
<?php
  @$username = $_POST['username'];
  @$password = $_POST['password'];
  $passwordcrip = md5($password);

  if((!$username) || (!$password)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    $passwordcrip = md5($password);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usr_users WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$passwordcrip}'");
    $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($login_check > 0){

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
          $key = stripslashes( $val );
          echo "";
        }

          $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
          $_SESSION['credits'] = $credits;

          mysql_query("UPDATE usr_users SET ultimo_log = now() WHERE id ='{$id}'");
          header("Location: index.php");
      }

    } else {
        echo  "<div class='right' style='background: rgb(173, 2, 2);width: 100%;height: 50px;line-height: 50px;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-left: 30px;color: white;'>
                Dados incorretos, tente novamente.
              </div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me dei a liberdade de fazer algumas melhorias no seu script, segue algumas delas:

Tratar os erros em vez de suprimi-los:

```
$username = (empty($_POST['username']) ? NULL : $_POST['username']);
$password = (empty($_POST['password']) ? NULL : $_POST['password']);
```

Remover `while`, pois teoricamente só teremos um nome de usuário para cada:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Remover *loop* desnecessário e usar o índice dos *arrays*:

```
$_SESSION['id']        =  $row['id'];
$_SESSION['username']  =  $row['username'];
$_SESSION['email']     =  $row['email'];
$_SESSION['credits']   =  $row['credits'];
```

Segue Script:

```
<?php

// Não é bom suprimir erros, pois erros deixam o script lento
// é melhor trata-los
$username = (empty($_POST['username']) ? NULL : $_POST['username']);
$password = (empty($_POST['password']) ? NULL : $_POST['password']);

$erro = FALSE;

if( !$username || !$password){
  $erro = TRUE;
  $msg = "Usuário e senha não devem ficar em branco";
} else {

   $passwordcrip = md5($password);

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usr_users WHERE username='{$username}'");
   $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);



   if($login_check > 0){

      // Teóricamente só terá um usuário, não precisara de while
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

      // Verifica senha
      if ($row['password'] != $passwordcrip) {
         $erro = TRUE;
         $msg  = 'Senha incorreta.';
      }

      // Verifica se usuário banido
      if ($row['ban']){
         $erro = TRUE;
         $msg  = 'Conta banida.';
      }


      // Se não houve erro prossegue
      if (!$erro){
         $_SESSION['id']        =  $row['id'];
         $_SESSION['username']  =  $row['username'];
         $_SESSION['email']     =  $row['email'];
         $_SESSION['credits']   =  $row['credits'];

         mysql_query("UPDATE usr_users SET ultimo_log = now() WHERE id ='{$id}'");

         header("Location: index.php");
         exit;
      }

  } else {
      $erro = TRUE;
      $msg = "Nenhum usuário encontrado.";
  }

}


   if ($erro)
      echo "<div class='right' style='background: rgb(173, 2, 2);width: 100%;height: 50px;line-height: 50px;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-left: 30px;color: white;'>{$msg}</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar o retorno do mysql e encontrar o indice de `ban` e fazer um `if` verificando se ele esta banido para realizar uma ação.

```
         if($row[0]['ban'] === '1'){
            echo 'usuário está banido e não pode logar.';
         }
```